# Fill new SQL column with rising integers with order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've added an integer row `SortNo` to an existing SQL table.

Now I want to fill the new `integer` column `SortNo` with integers rising by 10 (10, 20, 30, ...), BUT I want the rows to be ordered by another `nvarchar` column `Name`.

I can't just use Update, since it would set the `SortNo` in a random order, not ordered by `Name`.

So, how can I fill `SortNo` ordered by `Name`?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() * 10 with an ORDER BY Name is what my gut says

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using an updatable CTE and window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by [Name]) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set sortno = 10 * seqnum;
```

Comment: I just tried both - t is the table name. I added paratheses to [name], since name is a Keyword in SQL.

Comment: `t` is the name of the table.  `toupdate` is the CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Try This..

```
        UPDATE x
        SET x.[SortNo] = x.[SortNo]
        FROM (
              SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Name]) * 10 AS [SortNo]
              FROM table     
              ) x
```